# What does ${1} and ${*} do?

Tags: linux, bash, nagios

This [Nagios script](http://soren.klintrup.dk/_media/files/zpool/check_zpool.sh) uses `${1}` and `${*}` like so

```
if [ "${1}" ]; then
    if [ "${ERRORSTRING}" ]; then
        echo "${ERRORSTRING} ${OKSTRING}" | sed s/"^\/ "// | mail -s "$(hostname -s): ${0} reports errors\
" -E ${*}
    fi
else
    if [ "${ERRORSTRING}" -o "${OKSTRING}" ]; then
        echo "${ERRORSTRING} ${OKSTRING}" | sed s/"^\/ "//
        exit ${ERR}
    else
        echo no zpool volumes found
        exit 3
    fi
fi
```

**Question**

What does `${1}` and `${*}` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command-line arguments $1, $2, $3,...$9 are positional parameters, with $0 pointing to the actual command, program, shell script, or function and $1, $2, $3, ...$9 as the arguments to the command.

"$*" special parameter takes the entire list as one argument with spaces between and the "$@" special parameter takes the entire list and separates it into separate arguments.

Suppose test.sh given below:

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo "File Name: $0" 
echo "First Parameter : $1" 
echo "First Parameter : $2" 
echo "Quoted Values: $@" 
echo "Quoted Values: $*" 
echo "Total Number of Parameters : $#"
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) in the manual:

> *
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word
>   with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of
>   the `IFS` special variable. That is, `"$*"` is equivalent to `"$1c$2c…"`,
>   where `c` is the first character of the value of the `IFS` variable. If
>   `IFS` is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If `IFS` is null,
>   the parameters are joined without intervening separators.

`$1` refers to a [Positional Parameter](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters).

---

Assume the following script:

```
echo "${1}"
echo "${*}"
```

Upon invoking by saying:

```
bash scriptname foo bar baz
```

it would produce:

```
foo
foo bar baz
```

---

Now observe the effect of the variable `IFS`.  Given the script:

```
IFS=
echo "${1}"
echo "${*}"
echo "${@}"
```

Invoking it by saying:

```
bash scriptname "foo:hey you" bar baz
```

would produce:

```
foo:hey you
foo:hey youbarbaz
foo:hey you bar baz
```

Answer (score 1):

$1 is used(to display or to get input for user interactively) to display First parameter.

$* is used to show all parameters entered.

```
 # cat schecking.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "All values:" "$*"
 echo "Total number of Parameter(s) :" "$#"

 # ./schecking.sh
 All values:
 Total number of Parameter(s) : 0

 # ./schecking.sh It will help us to check
 All values: It will help us to check
 Total number of Parameter(s) : 6

 # cat schecking.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "First value is:" $1
 echo "All values:" "$*"
 echo "Total number of Parameter(s) :" "$#"

 # ./schecking.sh It will help us to check
 First value is: It
 All values: It will help us to check
 Total number of Parameter(s) : 6
```